# AutoHotkey MouseMove not centering properly

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

I'm running the below code and I expect the mouse to move to the center of the currently active window when I hit comma.....instead it is moving to different points on the screen, depending on where the window is on the screen.  It only centers the mouse properly when the window is positioned at the top left (x=0, y=0).

```
#NoEnv
SendMode Input
#WinActivateForce

Sysget, Mon2, Monitor, 2

,::

WinGetActiveStats, Title, Width, Height, X, Y
 {
MsgBox, The active window "%Title%" is %Width% wide`, %Height% tall`, and positioned at %X%`,%Y%.

;center_x:=X+(Width*.5)
;center_y:=Y+(Height*.5)

MouseMove, X+(Width*.5), Y+(Height*.5), 90

 }
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `CoordMode` in the documentation.

> Sets coordinate mode for various commands to be relative to either the
>   active window or the screen.
>
> CoordMode, ToolTip|Pixel|Mouse|Caret|Menu [, Screen|Window|Client]

The default `CoordMode` is `Screen` which is why you get two different locations.  Set the `CoordMode` to `Window` to assure that your mouse centering works on the active window.

You can set it for the entire script by calling it during the Auto-Execute section of the script.

Answer (score 1):

The following script will move mouse to Active Window on dual screen system.

I could not get it to work until I put in the sleep line, `WinGetPos` was getting info before the window had moved.

```
~#+right::
~#+left::
    Sleep,1000
    WinGetPos, X, Y, width, height, A
    center_x:=width/2
    center_y:=height/2
    MouseMove,center_x,center_y,
return
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be sure that Width and Height are the actual dimensions of the window and not the screen resolution.  Then check X and Y to ensure they're the actual top-left corner of the active window.

If the width and height are not from the actual window, i.e. the screen size, then this is expected behaivor.  Perhaps you could show us the calling function to get a better idea of where those parameters are coming from.

Comment: Trey, 
Per the following link, all variables I used should correspond to active window position/dimensions.  

http://autohotkey.free.fr/docs/commands/WinGetActiveStats.htm

The MsgBox shows that these are being read correctly, but the Mousemove is still not moving the mouse to the proper position.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that MousMove uses the coordinates of the window by default, so I changed the MouseMove line to the following:

```
MouseMove, Width*.5, Height*.5
```

All is good.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it all nothing works. The trick is to use `DllCall("SetCursorPos", int, x, int, y)`.
Here is the code to move mouse to center of window. Works on multi-montior and non-fullscreen windows.

```
MoveMouseInCenterOfActiveWindow:
CoordMode,Mouse,Screen
WinGetPos, winTopL_x, winTopL_y, width, height, A
;MouseMove, X, Y, 0 ; does not work with multi-monitor (always off)
    winCenter_x := winTopL_x + width/2
    winCenter_y := winTopL_y + height/2
DllCall("SetCursorPos", int, winCenter_x, int, winCenter_y)
Tooltip winTopL_x:%winTopL_x% winTopL_y:%winTopL_y% winCenter_x:%winCenter_x% winCenter_y:%winCenter_y%
return
```